Advanced custom fields keeping and managing relationship fields
I am trying to insert some data into the database using Advanced Custom Fields with relationship information and I can't find a way other than manually updating the relationships.
I have the following post types

Event
Registration

An event can have multiple registrations so I have a relationship field called
event_registrations.
A registration has a bi-directional field back to the event so that if a registration is deleted it removes it from the event too.
If I use the WP admin menus to manually add registrations I get a list of events to chose from. This all works well within the Admin Menus
However what I want to do is programatically add a registration. I have the event post_id and also the person post_id. I was hoping that I could someway just insert the post and have ACF manage the relationships but it is looking like I have to manage the registration array on the event myself.
Is there an easy way to do this or do I just have to suck it up and write the code? I'm sure that ACF would do it better than me anyway.
